# How to project camera background image onto mesh?

Tags: camera, texture-painting

I have set up camera background image with offset and scale,then how to project it onto mesh ?

Answer (score -1):

Check option **Apply camera Image** in **Options** in toolbar:

[image]

Also, available in **Properties**  Panel (<kbd>N</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: Can you tell the exact steps?Still confused.

Comment: This is as simple as it is. If your texture paint and UV is properly set up, you just press the button.